# How to convert data form in Google Sheet (Looping Date with Interval and Frequency)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to Convert Data From Table Schedulle, to Format Table Convert Data (Looping Date with Interval and Frequency)?

[ilustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ty3.png)

And here i attach the link Sheet
[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PxQPbrosYx7WIP6olVx4dG_9AISPumHdkspOHH1ITQ4/edit?usp=sharing).
Thankyou before!

New list data from DataTable Schedule [Convert Data Transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRKFy.png)

Comment: The process is called pivoting and I use an object to collect the data and reorganize it.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): **`DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.`** Would you please edit your question to include your data. [tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) has a free online service to create markdown tables.

Answer (score 0):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

You may use Google Apps Script to achieve what you would like based on the data that you have provided in the screenshot and the Google Sheet.

I have created an initial script that you may use for reference. It's been added to the link you posted as well so that you may play around with it. *Note: You may need to adjust the data range based on what you currently have.*

To access the script editor from the Google Sheet, click on **Extensions** > **Apps Script** from the toolbar.

[image: GOOGLE SHEET TOOLBAR]

You'll also be asked for some permissions the first time you run the script. You'll just need to allow it to proceed. It would look like this:

[image: APPS SCRIPT AUTHORIZATION]

### SAMPLE SCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var gV = ss.getRange("A3:D4").getValues(); // Gets the value of cells A3 to D4
  var out = []; // Created an empty array to be used in the function
  for (var j = 0; j < gV.length; j++) { // Loops through the row
    var currentDate = new Date(gV[j][0]) 
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(gV[j][2]); i++) { // Loops through the columns
      out.push([currentDate.toDateString(),gV[j][3]])
      var nDate = parseInt(gV[j][1]);
      currentDate = new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + nDate));
    }
  }
  var sV = ss.getRange("F3:G11").setValues(out); // Sets the value to cells F3 to G11 like in your example
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT]

### REFERENCES

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)